# Spring radiobutton jquery onchange function not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, spring, jsp

My js file contains the following:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=paymentOption]:radio').change(function () {
    alert('something');
}
```

And my jsp contains the following html:

```
<label><form:radiobutton name="paymentOption" path="usePaypal"
   value="true" checked="checked"/>Paypal
</label>

<label><form:radiobutton name="paymentOption" path="usePaypal"
                                             value="false"/>Card
</label>
```

I have tried quite a few variations of the css selector including:

```
$("input[type=radio][name='paymentOption']").on("change", function () {}
```

Can anyone pinpoint the issue I'm having?

**EDIT**

For those having the same problem - spring form tag requires the name used in the css selector to be the path and not the name as is the case with default html radiobuttons.

Comment: Assign change function inside a `$(document).ready`

Comment: Yeah this is nested in $(document).ready

Comment: `console.log($('input[type=radio][name=paymentOption]:radio'))` then what do you see in console ??

Comment: Not sure if i can do that with current setup. Any other ideas?

Comment: This is a web application right ? Then by console.log i mean on browsers console, while viewing this site, not in ide

Comment: So after moving the radiobutton to outside label it works?

Comment: console.log just shows the output in console it doesn't do anything, just to see weather the selector works

Comment: Either way - somehow managed to get function to work depending on location of radiobutton, so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call should like below

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("input[type=radio][name=usePaypal]").change(function () {

            if ($(this).val() == "true") {
                alert('true');
            } else {
                alert('false');
            }
        });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: running version 1.8.3

Comment: I have updated the code, since you are using spring tags so you have to use name=usePaypal instead of name=paymentOption